# To cite an organisation correctly in IEEE style

Tags: citations, bibtex

My tex based on Espanta's answer

```
@techreport{AAMI,
    title = {Recommended Practice for Testing and Reporting Performance Results of Ventricular Arrhythmia Detection Algorithms},
    institution = {{Association for the Advancement of Medical Instrumentation}},
    year = {1987},
    address = {Arlington, VA, USA}
}
```

which is shown correctly now after Espanta's answer in Bibliography.
However, the thing is shown in my text similarly as before :

[image]

where **AAM (1987)** is shown. 
I do not know what I should have in the text body for this citation, since the citation does not have author but institution.
I think **AAMI (1987)** is good.

**What is the correct way of citing this organisation in IEEE style?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is a technical report or white paper from certain company. Then it should not be misc type. I think if you change your item from misc to technical report, the IEEE style in latex will handle it.

The correct field in citation style should be
Authors(if any), title, publisher, address, year.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The other problem remains with having appropriate text when citing the document in the body.

Comment: Let LaTeX takes care of it. Supposedly LaTeX shld follow the style n we are not suppose to modify it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to

> I do not know what I should have in the text body for this citation, since the citation does not have author but institution. I think AAMI (1987) is good.

and

> The other problem remains with having appropriate text when citing the document in the body.

(comment to @Espanta)

When using LaTeX / Bibtex, you are not supposed to control how the citation appears in your text. **This is the task of the style that you are using**. Unless you have clear evidence that this is not the case, I would assume if a given journal requires you to use a given style, then **whatever text the style generates should be ok**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I simply leave it as it is with three first letters of the word **AAMI** in the citing.

Comment: @xLeitix, I did not recommend him to change the style, but I gave him a general clue that what it will look like. If he changes type from msc to proper type, the rest should be okay. Here is the point in answer _I think if you change your item from misc to technical report, the IEEE style in latex will handle it._